# HP ProBook instant shutdown after first logon the day

Tags: windows, shutdown, event-viewer, windows-10-v1903

Every morning my notebook is shutting itself instantly after the first logon with win hello.

There is nothing obvious written to the event log.

All the following application event raised through the startup and instant shutdown.
[image: win event log]

The second logon is every time successful as nothing happend.

The errors are raised by:

- *(first 6)* by Symantec (AV)
- *(second 2)* by TeamViewer 12

I'm pretty much stuck as nothing else is written to the event log in the other categories.

#### Details:

- Windows 10 1903 `Build 18362.356`
- TeamViever 12 `v12.0.78313`
- Symantec `v14.2.1031.0100`